# jquery catch events fired before .on()

Tags: jquery, events

I call `DIV.scrollTop(200)` function and only after bind `DIV.on('scroll')`, but `DIV.on('scroll')` catches `DIV.scrollTop(200)` event called before bind!

Why and how I can avoid that?

```
<div id="1" style="width:300px; height:300px; overflow:scroll; border:1px solid;">
     <div style="width:600px; height:600px; "></div>
</div>


$('#1').scrollTop(200);

$('#1').on('scroll', function(){
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/32sbufkn/1/)

Comment: Try delay your .on binding using a setTimeout

Comment: Good idea but I need no delay

Comment: I know you don't want to delay. But since the scroll behavior looks assynchronous, appliying a low delay like 1ms or 5ms should fix the issue. Maybe a zero ms delay also works.

Comment: 2ms delay works in Chrome, but I don't know about other browsers and whether this will be enough in the future browsers versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `scroll` event looks asynchronous, and even forcing an immediate repaint doesn't seem to work. Using vanilla JS instead of jQuery doesn't change the observed behavior either.

I don't see any way of programatically determining whether a `scroll` event was triggered by the user or by a script. I think adding a delay is your only workaround.

The repaint (which will trigger the `scroll` event) will occur after a `requestAnimationFrame` finishes, so attach the listener only *after*:

- `requestAnimationFrame` runs (indicating that a repaint will occur shortly), and
- after a `setTimeout` (indicating that the repaint has occurred)

```js
$('#1').scrollTop(200);

requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('#1').on('scroll', function() {
      $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" style="width:300px; height:300px; overflow:scroll; border:1px solid;">

  <div style="width:600px; height:600px; "></div>

</div>
```

This *will* work cross-browser, the mechanics of repainting timing is guaranteed by the specification.

Another possibility would be to add another `scroll` handler that runs *once*, and stops propagation of the event, so that the next handler doesn't see it:

```js
$('#1').scrollTop(200);

$('#1').one('scroll', function(event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$('#1').on('scroll', function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" style="width:300px; height:300px; overflow:scroll; border:1px solid;">

  <div style="width:600px; height:600px; "></div>

</div>
```